# How to measure the cold start time for an android application through android profiler

Tags: android

I have an android app, I want to know the cold start time for the app.

Can I do it through "profiler" tool in the android studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the profilier tool, you can simply use logcat. Once you launch your activity you will see an entry in logcat looking like:

> /ActivityManager: Displayed : com.your.app.package/.YourAppActivity|
>   launch : +1s364ms | stack_init : +1s364ms | uptime : +35m41s816ms